# We Are Number One, but …

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

## Task

Your task is to write a program that will take input, and then output the lyrics to [We Are Number One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfYnvDL0Qcw), changing specific words. The input will contain both the words to be changed, and the replacement word.

### Input

The input will be in the following format:

```
one, two\n
net, villain\n
```

(`\n` is a newline, it's not actually visible.) The input is assured to be this format, and the first word will always be a word the lyrics contains. But you can take input in whatever format you prefer the most.

### Output

Your output will be the entire We Are Number One lyrics, but with the words that are given in the input swapped.

Original lyrics:

```
Hey!
We are Number One
Hey!
We are Number One
```

Now listen closely
Here's a little lesson in trickery
This is going down in history
If you wanna be a Villain Number One
You have to chase a superhero on the run
Just follow my moves, and sneak around
Be careful not to make a sound
(Shh)
(CRUNCH)
(No, don't touch that!)

We are Number One
Hey!
We are Number One
We are Number One

Ha ha ha
Now look at this net, that I just found
When I say go, be ready to throw
Go!
(Throw it on him, not me!)
(Ugh, let's try something else)
Now watch and learn, here's the deal
He'll slip and slide on this banana peel!
(Ha ha ha, gasp! what are you doing!?)

Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number One
Hey!
Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number One
Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number One
Hey!
Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number One
Hey!
Hey![Source](http://genius.com/Lazy-town-we-are-number-one-lyrics)

### Rules

- The first word per input is assured to be in the lyrics.
- Your code must be case-insensitve (`one` as input will replace `One`)
- Trailing newlines are allowed.
- The input may be lower and uppercase, and the resulting output must have the same casing as the provided input.
- The input **can** try to replace e.g. `one` with `one`. If you replace it or not, is your choice.
- "Words" are sequences of characters seperated by space or commas, not by anything else (e.g. Hyphens), therefore `Ba` is not a valid input, but `Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba` is.

### Example case

Input:

```
one, three
net, villain
```

Output:

```
Hey!
We are Number three
Hey!
We are Number three
```

Now listen closely
Here's a little lesson in trickery
This is going down in history
If you wanna be a Villain Number three
You have to chase a superhero on the run
Just follow my moves, and sneak around
Be careful not to make a sound
(Shh)
(CRUNCH)
(No, don't touch that!)

We are Number three
Hey!
We are Number three
We are Number three

Ha ha ha
Now look at this villain, that I just found
When I say go, be ready to throw
Go!
(Throw it on him, not me!)
(Ugh, let's try something else)
Now watch and learn, here's the deal
He'll slip and slide on this banana peel!
(Ha ha ha, gasp! what are you doing!?)

Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number three
Hey!
Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number three
Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number three
Hey!
Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number three
Hey!
Hey!

## Winner

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the author of the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6043/41805)

Comment: Gotta love memes, do I get a bonus if I output a noise for the branch scene? ;)

Comment: also [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/103448/60919) - looks like all the memes are coming to PPCG!

Comment: Is there a reasonable way to do this other than producing the lyrics kolmogorov-complexity-style, then using your language's string replacement methods on the results? This seems like the concatenation of two separate challenges.

Comment: Does "here's" need to be handled as a word? Is "Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba" a word, or is each part a word? Can a word be replaced by another word that is itself a word to be replaced, and if so, do the replacements happen in sequence? Should the replacements preserve the capitalization of the original? Are the input words guaranteed to be lowercase? Are you guaranteed the song contains both words?

Comment: @xnor I believe all your questions should have been answered in the rules and retags now.

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of the pineapple one?

Comment: The pineapple one has a given pattern, this allows the input user to choose any word, not by pattern @EasterlyIrk

Comment: @devRicher hm, it's the same other than the forced capitals in some spots and the any-word-can-be-replaced.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk "It's the same except the task of the challenge is something else"

Comment: @devRicher nah, the KG but replacing words is the same (which is the main part of the challenge, just the little bits are different)

Comment: "Your code must be case-insensitve" is not good wording.

Comment: I see this question has very mixed opinions on it (half votes, half downvotes). Is there anything unclear with it?

Comment: In at least 2 answers below, the input was restricted to exactly two `word, word` pairs. The question doesn't seem to be clear on the range of the input. Should programs be able to handle an arbitrary amound of `word, word\n` pairs?

Comment: replace substrings or whole words only?

Comment: There has been a meta post regarding these sorts of questions: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11011/do-we-need-the-lyrics-tag. You can read it to see it our opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PHP, <s>661</s> 652 bytes

```php
for($s=base64_decode(gzuncompress("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"));$t=fgetcsv(STDIN);)$s=preg_replace("#\b$t[0]\b#i",$t[1],$s);echo$s;
```

`gzinflate` is 3 bytes shorter than `gzuncompress`, but `gzcompress` has the shorter output.

And: The other PHP answer replaces substrings, not words. I´d save 8 more bytes with that.

**breakdown**

```php
for($s="text";                              // init text
    $t=fgetcsv(STDIN);)                     // loop through STDIN lines
    $s=preg_replace("#\b$t[0]\b#i",$t[1],$s);   // replace pairs
echo$s;                                     // output
```

Answer (score 12):

### PHP, 666 bytes

I suppose this is a rather appropriate code size for a song about Villains...

```php
<?$s=gzinflate(base64_decode("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"));foreach($argv as$a){@list($a,$b)=explode(",",$a);$s=str_ireplace($a,$b,$s);}echo $s;
```

Usage: `php numberOne.php one,three net,villain`

Comment: upvote for the combination of villains + 666 + php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bzcompress.php should save some bytes and replace `echo $s;` with `echo$s;`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.6, 695 bytes

```
import re 
import zlib,base64

a=input().split(', ')
t = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(b'eJzNks+KGzEMxu9+Cs0pCcw+w8LuoUkPKbT7hx6VsRK70VjB9uzgt68000KhWyj0UiKCsYW+7/tp9tQ690qAmeA4jSfK8CmR279/7dxRZuBYKiUYWApx095MmwKo97UyAVMpkiAmqDkOV8rNPYVYQOsiMV3Ay7w862UVfT2cockEM6aEcFJReInMqB2/SH/VjoBvBFVgCFisrUw3yoGygOrVQJCn5D5OpcJZmNXp2GCUNyo9YPJQEuFVI8mUvHsgGDTdeWJIUm3qiNdl6PK8/RLCzm0fPz8fH/d6OEqvvtPGOqchqBrWbqdA/prdezT3qJm0Vqwi6k4FDFai2i8icIBvayKz9RoU/AEKNmXZG6xM6JvZryHL7D5I57ZPdoRYDUuIY78kHEn9bp8vodcNVV1YzU3DjqR6uhTiQrvFx4xVAxowJsyph7Au2AB7QtaAG2YoHG8rVo6e1g2o8RMm/cGNiNXJz4A9XLDcOpgtkWGwhXv7Grp7o/iAdyet6D235fSjNCLe/VZ/gv7PU/4TG8sU+/sO/HItbg==')).decode('utf8')
for i in xrange(0,len(a),2):
    t = t.replace(a[i],a[i+1])
print t
```

**Output**

Hey!
    We are Number three
    Hey!
    We are Number three

```
Now listen closely
Here's a little lesson in trickery
This is going down in history
If you wanna be a Villain Number three
You have to chase a superhero on the run
Just follow my moves, and sneak around
Be careful not to make a sound
(Shh)
(CRUNCH)
(No, don't touch that!)


We are Number three
Hey!
We are Number three
We are Number three


Ha ha ha
Now look at this villian, that I just found
When I say go, be ready to throw
Go!
(Throw it on him, not me!)
(Ugh, let's try something else)
Now watch and learn, here's the deal
He'll slip and slide on this banana peel!
(Ha ha ha, gasp! what are you doing!?)


Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number three
Hey!
Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number three
Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number three
Hey!
Ba-ba-biddly-ba-ba-ba-ba, ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba-ba
We are Number three
Hey!
Hey!
```

Comment: The `word-to-replace, word` arguments should be dynamic. At the moment, you hardcoded it to have exactly 2 arguments with the to-be-replaced words always being `One` and `net`. Also, there's *a lot* of golfing potential there. You can disregard `input` entirely and take the string as a function argument, write everything in one line, compress the text (substitution, zlib come to mind), use shorter variable names, replace `re.I` and `re.X` with their numerical values. Additionally, this doesn't even run as `word1` and `word2` aren't defined (you probably meant `w1` and `w2`.

Comment: edited my code...

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3.4, 666 bytes

```
import zlib,base64,sys,re;s=zlib.decompress(base64.b85decode(b'c%03W&uSwv494$%3e71AOrN399-8!!!fyYtM`f(UZZuY~Jste^D|@=Iuw5whQX+z}g}(3mX|_~4^Fn};U_XrqitrG~Y(Ks>W-l|aPniM?EQz>iZ=_WM)cc&7fGH&j-~;67hcm@u9-U91brK&=U}bL4dYMIEcSk5P!Hgjw98?sZJu_;@U(&y{!{Hl278o3++LopZMMqIU^|B*~Q!w{a%5W5BbvhOp<&9Dg7%Zefc-BZV1#4~y22FRI7=q+Fb;NTU+Md@xo!gl8?T@GZ?N$$a>D6~w)y`>fs)o7SD3H&?`v|AmqNdVXz>26pm8iG^<-W<l4qlf`)!2(u^gBpclxAOXMM7I@fb62o=1w}Zeym6Exq@+i>|4f>)baZ1<a*sv)|KU0H10^Mr)wcjv}rzO%o?#GW5O7EaLbA-VoS)HaK#LX{bd2m-qNxIHGaULKe!OFI{6c@hZCkt2XjqSIn<Tg`aN{ljpGeo9kjf)T-xcqG$UU9Q~$&M<tg99Mw?RqegpM6EsO')).decode('utf8');
for a in sys.argv[1:]:x,y=a.split(', ');s=re.sub(x,y,s,99,2);
print(s)
```

Edits:

- Used regex replace instead of replace so that it works case insensitive.
- Used command line to get the parameters instead of input.

Comment: Your solution appears to accept only two text pairs. Also, you have to split at `, `, not just `,`. You can golf this down by converting it into a function `import zlib,base64
def h(a,b):return "string".decode('utf8').replace(*a.split(", ")).replace(*b.split(", "))`. Note that this will be still incorrect as the number of args is limited to 2. It also seems that you have compressed the wrong lyrics; when I decompressed your string I got the version with `We are Number three`, which is an *example output* in the question above.

Comment: Changed it to the correct text & split at ', ', question didn't mention that there could be more than 2 inputs. Also noted that it's case sensitive so some rework to be done it seems.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 842 bytes

```
•®_Ç²îü!úïæ²|ˆ9¶iˆtˆEC}#©ÿ®cÖ:|®¥÷K*œÒÅ5œ1‚ÂlÊÎ¤Nç·’±Ðá×ÍÐý5WÝã¢®ìÖ$hVbPGwÎ·M;9O|‰¶ÉèëøËöç¡QÒµ5‚aC}.*gbJÇ¦>);&f€ZÛ}íóÉh\„Ú;Ts§ÞT¿QZëDò©®#ÑSHžûd¦Óéó”ó\ê§ø5|PšÍÖcyÐÁ:hŒ02¨ÄùSûíi¯—àR›ÿR{3Í)Ú×E<u¥°¼:—jth€ƒWÆªâþ=—vJ†ÀJûy6Áv\TÈÞåšöQë£Âb„ˆ@Ò6^#ˆL*ÁöªAWçàˆÌä£#«ùÁ°è;sq¯¸GšìááÐ©–ob¾§m^¹+ò"-Å£‘u·ãÿ?ù÷7Á^)8GÑ<oßÝ7Åjœq–[—'XuDÔÈìïÃ÷áÓ´‚ñ)©™à$ÝS¢¦(ð8M'§›¬§³N(En"H#«Ÿß½µ`Å´½axxq\òÝP@HÓ‘š£m—‹váøÃGàhT™ËUc·€ô~¥CEw6G¥Âã”ú¾&º™e,"AÂy±²ÅÜÚMâ2qtBaaª.^`òÍ–Ú$¦~z¢PÇR²”6â#”½Ì0ÂVêž]oÉ¦s¯Ž½Ç˜ûRG™¸§I?™µ¦½ÀÓþæ8i‚%‘L#]ÒXÓ†A“r*Å;E%c¾0H;ø<½yÎ=^ù_í<ÃòõŽŸq!ùßN÷wP0q1¹‰~Õ¿´zÿgI,¸$ž¬…ÃÊGÖ¢e¸ŒHFMcw,Î()¼ü»T×–r{&h·q²¬5¡ýWÑÈú¬«ñÚRóD›<üŽ‹Nê*¹f¦›þÆYÓ–hýÂ}§l<Ñò<Ýù†ïÓi#‹k€ö#[ûlù_=¡ç·FÜØ]¢n©l›ÜÍ,ÉˆØrôN5Ô¸¹NGúoÝ][{½ãÚ;S*ÌåÙC€\À=k½;qU,pT$Ÿ5uÕœ¼§/›Kàô™eéù‚.Úæ·vx¾Xugvš–ûî?øc}|/žr¡¶µt…’öà,2;ˆ«=ÆF5£ØÓ¯~À|ýÝÓß]nLÔ<ëïÂåkQ`µ3DxÐ‘!´‚Ù7AÏmi¦nvgã…ñ•121B"012345678"¶" ()!,-'?"«‡¹',¡vyN²',¡è.:}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#JVRpV1NXFP3eX1ESlKERGRpAEooIGEBIGaI4ADI0EpShARJAhvWIEouK1QQRUyIZ5AVIJBAgAyFhrbPX65f8i/dH6Hmrn@5d7927zz5773OvZCFAh0/xhmI4xEUezhGFSLHFnPMWxUdzzpmcs6lhSU37uKTDYWzWLNIh7SJxr1hyw4VVreQukwUPHGN4iw/03YgQJWThKx3jI/z4gnVeM9oeeBEkLoUINvMtD4Y6DLN8PNGuu/X7oiwcURxr2EMYSbxDnDH8nXDRmZahBxuWSopHhlqZo/hbke76M9kReYx/lvADJ1iz9MrCN3h0pmkK4ZuJLjsfI9yIGO3ToRqfupulLNJ/kAg39nEiC16c9OKAzya1ix2Sn@ltDs8zxZUai@QqLac9vEaqG2n8GKWoLGzA1yUL57jsWqjAehE8@NKkt9EuHdFFDf9@PmNhOv@6euCkAwSQreWP9lZZ8EFoRXq@Eiv2XhP@wjfscrV4J8IUhGOISeect@Gq7FfnnG3FWEGcDup7EIIv58R7fKegmsJIYYWOsKebtlKUkgZGiLCofnykfVlwTw5RlkLj/ZT6BTHVDaxSUBa2bJRAEJd1fDlRhZX@omoDPuknsQNvFVafS24rX33CNAse2hqxwdwi7PkrJBjXTaeKmcdFjP86AF8@vN3smliIo@r2AgqxFBShEJ0YC5smVM1MUUpihzJ0NsDVTykzODdn7UUM3o7bzXAzG8lPwXEuJgspOxdI4pUBPotJQX93f5ij4ojgdJl2G5pmKw0cLAeCiknnlL1O53zKrFHVwzFPxxzQVWzD045AuXXmzuAgHZT0D3CpdW4HnnwSl19SoANvuijGCJUIqHmhDN6XwvEAB1K2bxJrJE5TVMrw5ze5baS7DFyCkhRqqVM2ZyTyH4GzkoVYPcpSXOMW2tR9cD1UuvHVy8L2VDFWdU3Xhilb2qxDUk@ZeXyo7UfqKX7oWccYzqSMlLTmsQE7RiRmO0qtZZTikC/jM13S6UtcjrRoKJkvZSkiCyLfeWvAJgXMlJRczXfbh2c1@FBYRBe4oLQJX7jBqYXrFkpYKUYRLfmR6cEnNk4xI4xjeLpw0sje6HEhZVhpIw6KKfWMRCW6WTgfKeTdFmTgWKLQmJ4vx/Q8kSklp1G4R1mq1AvFirj6CdJj3EstV@FJvsuSb/VRYIL2xxSwbaxrsMYR3ZrCqVGLDRYvZTTgfBLevicLrF6Qh7G7mCO8i68NDNkLofYFZXTW@5o/TflSUmvDZ8lNFxS6yYD34MOpYjNPJ7PxlPCEiZSwz1H2oW3ELvkVc9M4rENyeGnxppSdIj/F6WyGdeNXhp8Kn6Zcl3NSuBbOu1qerS0OcXQZwiJ362Und/om2rCh56clyuHafdE5QGcVjXP4yM7m/R/3r1X1@Ht8lMQJ@4gSPxHH/CyWlZfdUZWWlVf8qq2sqlZRXPVzYVGe5kZBnYrCsuCnVIGG/PZ5I8WUDfZKapauroy28SHzlKbHrHk0adOYLKPTPzVYzOZpM@/N85oWXgZn/gM)

Simplistic approach, didn't do anything but replace symbols with integers, convert from base-121 to base-214. Then I decompress it, re-replace the characters and perform replacement on the words. For testing I suggest replacing pronouns with other pronouns.